# 74LS90N Is not counting!

Tags: clock, 555, counter

So basically Im working on a counter from  0-9 and I have made a simulation and it works completely fine but when I implement it on the breadboard it does not count. I have implemented it more than 4 times and Im sure that there is no error in placing wires. Im using a 555 timer to make a delay of 1 second.

- Am I Using The Correct IC , 74LS90N?
- Should I Use 7490N Only?
- I heard about adding a 0.01uF capacitor somewhere in the circuit, not sure where.

Here is the schematic: 
[image]

UPDATE: I grounded the un-used pins. Still not counting.

Comment: Are VCC and GND connected?

Comment: yes they are connected, the simulation does that itself.

Comment: Have you tied the unused pins to the appropriate rails?

Comment: Do I have to tie the unused pins somewhere? Can you please tell that where they have to go? Vcc or GND ?(Kinda a noob)

Comment: So, the simulation works, and VCC and Gnd are connected automatically... But what about on your breadboard? I got confused by your question, and the your comments.

Comment: Show the breadboard and show the traces of the signals to the pins

Comment: Yes, tie the unused inputs to ground to make it count.

Comment: is the vcc and ground connected on your breadboard? (double check with a multimeter)

Comment: pins 2,3,6 and 7 should be grounded (0V) - see http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/counter/bcd-counter-circuit.html

Comment: Besides needing to connect Vcc and GND to the physical 74LS90, your schematic symbol for the 7447 is missing the necessary connections to Vcc (pin 16) and GND (pin 8). Look up the datasheets if you haven't already.

Comment: They are automatically connected to their respective +ve and -ve in the simulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should ALWAYS tie unused inputs somewhere.

This is especially true of control pins, but is also true for other inputs. Obviously, if you do not tie the control pins appropriately the device will not act as you expect. Tying other unused general inputs, although not required to ensure functionality, prevents noise in the system from causing unnecessary switching internal to the device and additional unwanted power consumption and potentially more EMI radiation.

Which way you tie them depends on the function of the pin..

For example .. if it is an "Enable" pin you need to tie it to the rail that enables it. However, if it is say a "Clear" pin you need to tie it to the rail that does not clear it. Check out the devices truth table to determine what to tie where.

You can tie the unused pins directly to the rail, however it is preferred to use appropriately sized pull-up or pull-down resistors. If you have multiple pins to tie, you can share a resistor for this, however if the design is new, and on a PCB, it is often prudent to use individual resistors for each pin. If you need to use that pin later in rework, the latter will save you a lot of grief. If it is tied directly to the rail, and the PCB has a ground plane, rework becomes a nightmare involving lifting the pin during manufacture.

Once the board becomes a mature product, you can remove the extra resistors on the final revision of the PCB as a cost reduction step.

Example imaginary device.....

[image]

The resistor sizes need to be small enough to ensure the input is pulled to the required logic voltage with sufficient current to be insensitive to noise, while not incurring too much wasted current. If using a single resistor for many pins, that should include the current for all pins attached to it.

CMOS devices are easier to handle since they are symmetrical and have much lower currents. TTL on the other hand requires a much smaller resistor for pull-downs than pull-ups. That's why we generally pull-up when we have a choice.

Rule of thumb resistor math ...

\$R_{pulldown} = V_{IL}/(2*I_{IL})\$ For a single pin on an LS90 that's ~\$150R\$

\$R_{pullup} = (Vcc-V_{IH})/(2*I_{IH})\$ For a single pin on an LS90 that's ~\$18K\$.

For TTL, 20K pull-ups is ok but, 10K is more common. I think we used to buy the latter by the ton.

Comment: Im not intending to make it a mature product, It's just a experiment I am trying to do. :) However, the thing you mentioned , I will keep it under consideration.

Comment: I am facing another problem that is, when i connect the VCC and GND to the rail of next breadboard and put an LED in that rail, the timer LED stops blinking. When I take out the LED from the second rail, the timer LED starts blinking again.

Comment: Can you tell how small ? Like I do have many resistors.

Comment: @MuhammadYasirJaved can't help you with your other problem, but it is likely a wiring issue somewhere.

Comment: @MuhammadYasirJaved see my update for R calculation

Comment: I already saw it, looks great.
p.s the voltage regulator is not working properly

Comment: @MuhammadYasirJaved - For TTL and LSTTL you can simply tie unused low inputs directly to ground. As for tieing high, use a single 1k resistor and you can connect 10 or more inputs in parallel with a single resistor. Alternatively, if you have an unused inverting gate handy (NOT, NOR or NAND) you can tie the input to ground and use the output as a source of logic high for up to 20 inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the power(VCC) and ground being connected on either the 74LS90 or the 7447.

You should place the capacitor close to the 74LS90 between the VCC and GND. Keep the wiring between the IC and capacitor short.

Comment: since its a simulation, it connects the vcc and ground itself  
and that capacitor is for time delay

Comment: Connect the GND and the VDD, on the breadboard. And add  0.1UF cap from pin 8 to pin 16 of each 7490.

Comment: 0.1 or 0.01 capacitor?

Comment: The value is relatively unimportant.  It should be a ceramic capacitor as they have the right high-frequecny properties and should have short leads to the power and ground connections of the IC.

Answer (score 0):

All those unused pins should be tied to GND. I am pretty sure you will find it working then.

The capacitor Kevin White mentioned is a good idea. You should google decoupling capacitors if you want more information on why this is good practise.

The 0.01uF you said you heard could be used somewhere in the circuit could be on the 555 timer. It is connected between pin 5 on the 555 timer and GND. It is talked about [HERE](http://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/basic-555-circuit-capacitor-not-needed.121576/).